# Browsers are not able to access internet?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, windows-10, internet-connection

Even though it's being displayed that I have internet access (ethernet) internet explorer and chrome is not able to access internet.

It is displaying as no internet connection.

WiFi is working since I am able to access internet through my phone.

When I update Windows defender it is updating so I can assume that some apps can access internet.

How do I make my browsers up and running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to start, open CMD as RUn as Admin
2. Type  just "/netsh" [enter], and then "/int ip reset resetlog.txt",
3. Reboot the system.

Comment: try resetting "netsh winsock", just by typing "netsh winsock reset" in the CMD and then reboot.